# Is it possible to condense code to allow multiple variables instead of a line per variable?

Tags: javascript

I am using a small script that adds custom selections to a dropbox using the following code

```
if (typeof customsum1 != "undefined") { editsummAddOptionToDropdown(dropdown, customsum1); }
if (typeof customsum2 != "undefined") { editsummAddOptionToDropdown(dropdown, customsum2); }
if (typeof customsum3 != "undefined") { editsummAddOptionToDropdown(dropdown, customsum3); }
```

and so on. This is expandable by adding more lines, but since the variables have the same format, is there a way to condense this to theoretically allow infinite custom selections as long as the set variables follow the customsum# format?

Comment: Have you tried using a loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an array and a loop:

```
var sums = [customsum1, customsum2, customsum3];

for (var i=0; i<sums.length; i++) {
    if (typeof sums[i] !== 'undefined') {
         editsummAddOptionToDropdown(dropdown, sums[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach requires hard-coding the `sums` array, and a such doesn't address op's request for a theoretical infinite  number of elements.

Comment: typeof[anything] always returns "object" - correct use of typeof is: typeof variable.
I edited this, but it seems someone else was faster.

Comment: @Madbreaks The elements have to be added somewhere. The array can be generated by different means. (Kolink shows an example using "global variables"). In any case, this level of reduction is usually sufficient ..

Comment: Why? See the answer posted by @Kolink - use array notation plus string concatenation to identify the members that you've hard-coded in `sums` .

Comment: @Madbreaks See the *second* part of Kolink's answer where he/she *implies that the first approach is "not advisable"*

Comment: @pst I read it. No explanation as to *why* it's not advisable. However I still feel this answer does not meet op's requirement: *"theoretically allow infinite custom selections as long as the set variables follow the customsum# format"*.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed both answers are essentially the same, just different variable names. Thank you for the answers. I'm still learning js, so didn't think of a loop and an array, even though I've used them before.

Comment: @Madbreaks - Code has to be written somewhere.  If variables are used, those almost certainly must be hard-coded.  For illustrative purposes, a hard coded array is adequate.  Obviously the array can be generated dynamically.  That's not the point.  The point is to use an array rather than individual variables.

Comment: Clarifying what is "hardcoded" and what is not, the variables would be considered, uh, variable, while this loop, and the rest of the script, should be untouched. This particular script is going to be used in a wiki, and the variables would be declared in a user's skin script page while the rest of the script is in one place.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming these are global variables, you can use a loop:

```
for( var i=1; i<=3; i++) {
    if( typeof window['customsum'+i] != "undefined") editsummAddOptionToDropdown(dropdown,window['customsum'+i]);
}
```

However, it would be advisable to use an array anyway:

```
var customsum = [
    /* what you normally have for customsum1 */,
    /* same for customsum2 */,
    ...
];
for( var i=0, l=customsum.length; i<l; i++) {
    if( typeof customsum[i] != "undefined") editsummAddOptionToDropdown(dropdown,customsum[i]);
}
```

Comment: I agree that Matt's answer seems to still require hardcoding the script if more variables are added, following the comments there. Using this code, I assume I can just replace the declarations of customsum1, customsum2, etc. with `var customsum` correct?

Comment: @user1944206 instead of using (potentially-infinite) variables following a common naming pattern, you should really just **store the values in an array to begin with.**